# Rails undefined local variable or method inside constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do some code refactor from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65069467/rails-replace-3-classes-to-be-in-line-with-dry). I've got a build method:

```
  def build
    outgoing_invoices_balance = outgoing_invoices_sum - outgoing_invoices_taxes
    incoming_invoices_balance = -incoming_invoices_sum + incoming_invoices_taxes
    recurring_expenses_balance = -recurring_expenses_sum + recurring_expenses_taxes
    recurring_revenues_balance = recurring_revenues_sum - recurring_revenues_taxes
    expense_contracts_balance = -expense_contracts_sum + expense_contracts_taxes
    revenue_contracts_balance = revenue_contracts_sum - revenue_contracts_taxes
  end
```

Depends on action type passed in the method call I want to trigger a specific sum action. To do so I defined instance variable `ACTIONS` which is a hash of sum defined earlier variables Refactored build method below:

```
  ACTIONS = {
    'revenues_sum' => outgoing_invoices_balance + recurring_revenues_balance + revenue_contracts_balance,
    'expenses_sum' => incoming_invoices_balance + recurring_expenses_balance + expense_contracts_balance,
    'total_sum' => outgoing_invoices_balance + incoming_invoices_balance + recurring_expenses_balance +
                   recurring_revenues_balance + expense_contracts_balance + revenue_contracts_balance
  }

  def build
    outgoing_invoices_balance = outgoing_invoices_sum - outgoing_invoices_taxes
    incoming_invoices_balance = -incoming_invoices_sum + incoming_invoices_taxes
    recurring_expenses_balance = -recurring_expenses_sum + recurring_expenses_taxes
    recurring_revenues_balance = recurring_revenues_sum - recurring_revenues_taxes
    expense_contracts_balance = -expense_contracts_sum + expense_contracts_taxes
    revenue_contracts_balance = revenue_contracts_sum - revenue_contracts_taxes

    ACTIONS[action_name]
  end
```

When I passed e.g. `revenues_sum` as `action_name` I'm getting an error:

> undefined local variable or method `outgoing_invoices_balance'

Comment: The scope of that constant `ACTIONS` is different from that of the instance method `build`. You don't have access to instance-level variables/methods from that class context.

Answer (score 1):

`ACTIONS` is a constant, where the value is a Hash. By the time Ruby evaluates the constant, Ruby needs to know the value of `outgoing_invoices_balance` which is not known at this time. This is similar if you would write

```
MYCONST=outgoing_invoices_balance
```

When the constant is defined, the value is not known, unless you have a method of this name available at this point.

One possibility would be to define your actions a `Proc` object. The Proc needs to get as parameter a class, where `outgoing_invoices_balance` and so on, are instance methods. Example:

```
ACTIONS = {
  'revenues_sum' => lambda {|o| o.outgoing_invoices_balance + o.recurring_revenues_balance + ro.evenue_contracts_balance,
  # and so on
}
```

If you have a String denoting an action stored in the variable `action`, and an object which "knows" about the balances stored in the variable `myobj`, you could invoke the action by

```
ACTIONS[action].call(myobj)
```